# Can I use a variable condition in a CASE statement?

Tags: sql

Picture this table of interactions a business has with people:

```
+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+
| user_name | action_timestamp    | action          |
+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+
| john      | 2017-01-01 10:00:00 | phone_call      |
+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+
| john      | 2017-01-02 12:00:00 | became_customer |
+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+
| john      | 2017-01-03 14:00:00 | phone_call      |
+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+
| jane      | 2016-08-06 10:00:00 | phone_call      |
+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+
| jane      | 2016-08-06 11:00:00 | phone_call      |
+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+
| jane      | 2016-08-06 12:00:00 | became_customer |
+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+
| tony      | 2016-12-01 15:00:00 | phone_call      |
+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+
```

I want to get to something like this:

```
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| user_name | total_actions | is_customer | became_customer     | interactions_before_customer | interactions_after_customer |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| john      | 3             | TRUE        | 2017-01-02 12:00:00 | 1                            | 1                           |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| jane      | 3             | TRUE        | 2016-08-06 12:00:00 | 2                            | 0                           |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| tony      | 1             | FALSE       | NULL                | 1                            | 0                           |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

The first 4 columns are trivial with some grouping and CASEs, but I don't know how to do columns 5 and 6 (interactions before customer and interactions after customer) since the case is predicated on the result of a previous column, and needs to vary between rows.

Is this simpler than it appears? If anybody cares I don't work at a call center, it's just a much simpler analogue to what I'm trying to do ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you an idea. I have tested this on `ORACLE` and it is working fine,

```
WITH CUS_DET AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM INTERACTIONS
    WHERE ACTION = 'became_customer'
)
SELECT INTERACTIONS.USER_NAME
  , SUM(CASE 
    WHEN (CUS_DET.ACTION_TIMESTAMP IS NULL
            OR INTERACTIONS.ACTION_TIMESTAMP < CUS_DET.ACTION_TIMESTAMP)
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
  END) BEF
  , SUM(CASE 
    WHEN INTERACTIONS.ACTION_TIMESTAMP > CUS_DET.ACTION_TIMESTAMP 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
  END) AFT
FROM INTERACTIONS
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CUS_DET
    ON INTERACTIONS.USER_NAME = CUS_DET.USER_NAME
GROUP BY INTERACTIONS.USER_NAME;
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using conditional aggregation if a user can only become a customer once:

```
select 
    t.user_name
  , case when c.action_timestamp is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Is_Customer
  , c.action_timestamp as became_customer
  , count(case when t.action_timestamp < coalesce(c.action_timestamp,'2525-01-01') then 1 end) as interactions_before_customer 
  , count(case when t.action_timestamp > c.action_timestamp then 1 end) as interactions_after_customer 
from t
  left join t as c
    on t.user_name = c.user_name
      and c.action = 'became_customer'
group by t.user_name, c.action_timestamp
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/LOUGN53032

```
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| user_name | Is_Customer |   became_customer   | interactions_before_customer | interactions_after_customer |
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| tony      | No          | NULL                |                            1 |                           0 |
| jane      | Yes         | 2016-08-06 12:00:00 |                            2 |                           0 |
| john      | Yes         | 2017-01-02 12:00:00 |                            1 |                           1 |
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Argh sorry it's so hard to choose between these answers! I wanted to choose this one just because you're a SQL celebrity and I learned about coalesce, but Pons works too and he got in a few minutes early. Thank you for the reply :)